# Creating Unique Number in XSLT on the basis of current Date Time

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is the XSLT I am using.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:variable name="nl">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="tb">
        <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <!-- Open the root array -->
        <!--<xsl:text>[{</xsl:text>-->
    <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nl" />
        <!-- Process all the child nodes of the root -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="subitem" >
            <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="$tb" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <!-- Close the root array -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$nl" />
        <!--<xsl:text>}]</xsl:text>-->
  <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="subitem" >
        <!-- child element at any level. The indent parameter allows for better layout of the output JSON -->
        <xsl:param name="indent"/>
        <!-- newindent is used as the indent for children of this node -->
        <xsl:variable name="newindent">
            <xsl:value-of select="$indent" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$tb"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- output the name of this node in quotes, ready for the content to follow -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$indent" />
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:text>" :</xsl:text>
        <!-- check if this node has children, if not, simply output the text value, otherwise outoput an array -->
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=" count( ./* ) = 0 ">
                <!-- This is a text value only -->
                <xsl:text> "</xsl:text>
                <!-- Make sure that any embedded quotes are escaped -->
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace">"</xsl:with-param>
                    <xsl:with-param name="by">\"</xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <!-- check if we need a comma and a new line, not required if this is the last output value -->
                <xsl:if test=" position() != last() ">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$nl" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- This node has children, so we need to process them as an array -->
                <!-- Array opening -->
                <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$nl" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$newindent" />
                <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$nl" />
                <!-- Process all the elements in the array (recursive call to this template) -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="subitem" >
                    <xsl:with-param name="indent">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$newindent" />
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
                <!-- Close the array -->
                <xsl:value-of select="$nl" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$newindent" />
                <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$nl" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$indent" />
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
                <!-- If this is not the last node then we need a comma and line feed -->
                <xsl:if test=" position() != last() ">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$nl" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
        <!-- This code provided thanks to @codesling on stackoverflow -->
        <xsl:param name="text" />
        <xsl:param name="replace" />
        <xsl:param name="by" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text"
                        select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the output I am getting is as below

```
{
    "ReferenceNumber" : "",
    "ProductCode" : "",
    "AccountNumber" : "",
    "TransactionNumber" : "",
    "FromDate" : "",
    "ToDate" : "",
    "FromAmount" : "",
    "ToAmount" : ""
}
```

In the output , I want to pass unique reference number in the ReferenceNumber tag. Format of the same will be **UNIQU000000DDMMYYYYHHMMSS**
**MM - Month
YYYY - Year
HH - Hour
MM - Minute
SS - Seconds.**
Just wanted to know , is there any option in XSLT to generate unique reference number like this. I have an idea to generate unique reference like this is C# but not in XSLT.

Comment: I don't understand your question. First, XSLT 1.0 (which you appear to be using) does not know the current date or time, unless your processor can get it from some extension function it supports. Next, if your "unique reference number" is based on the current date time, then what's the point of including both? If you meant to generate a **random** number to add to the date and time, then again the answer is no, XSLT 1.0 cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

Getting expected output using below XSLT.

```
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
    <msxsl:assembly name="System.Collections"/>
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
    <msxsl:assembly name="System.Data"/>
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.IO" />
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Xml"/>
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Security.Cryptography" />
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Web"/>
    <msxsl:assembly name="System.Web" />
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Text" />

    <![CDATA[
 public string GetJson(string ReferenceNumber = null,
        string ProductCode = null,
        string AccountNumber = null,
        string TransactionNumber = null,
        string FromDate = null,
        string ToDate = null,
        string FromAmount = null,
        string ToAmount = null)
    {

        string currentDateTime = string.Format("UNIQU000000{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}", DateTime.Now.Day.ToString("00"), DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("00"), DateTime.Now.Year.ToString("0000"), DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("00"), DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("00"), DateTime.Now.Second.ToString("00"));
        string jsonOutput = string.Format("{{\"ReferenceNumber\" :\"{0}\",\"ProductCode\" : \"{1}\",\"AccountNumber\" : \"{2}\",\"TransactionNumber\" : \"{3}\",\"FromDate\" : \"{4}\",\"ToDate\" : \"{5}\",\"FromAmount\" : \"{6}\",\"ToAmount\" : \"{7}\"}}",
            currentDateTime, ProductCode, AccountNumber, TransactionNumber, FromDate, ToDate, FromAmount, ToAmount);

        return jsonOutput;
    }
]]>
</msxsl:script>
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/Request">
    <xsl:variable name="referenceNumber" select="ReferenceNumber" />
    <xsl:variable name="productCode" select="ProductCode" />
    <xsl:variable name="accountNumber" select="AccountNumber" />
    <xsl:variable name="transactionNumber" select="TransactionNumber" />

    <xsl:variable name="fromDate" select="FromDate" />
    <xsl:variable name="toDate" select="ToDate" />
    <xsl:variable name="fromAmount" select="FromAmount" />
    <xsl:variable name="toAmount" select="ToAmount" />
    <xsl:variable name="jsonRequest" select="user:GetJson($referenceNumber,$productCode,$accountNumber,$transactionNumber,$fromDate,$toDate,$fromAmount,$toAmount)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$jsonRequest"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Output :

```
{"ReferenceNumber" :"UNIQU00000019072017162234","ProductCode" : "","AccountNumber" : "","TransactionNumber" : "","FromDate" : "","ToDate" : "","FromAmount" : "","ToAmount" : ""}
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is completely deterministic, it can't produce random numbers by itself. Your best plan is to either write an extension function that does what you need, or pass in either the date or the random value you need through a parameter using

```
<xsl:param name="datetime"/>
```

as a child of the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element.